# Как преобразовать tsv ответ яндекс директ api в массив?

Tags: php, массивы, яндекс-директ

Получаю отчет яндекс директа:

```
"a259784,259785 (2017-03-19 - 2018-03-19)"
AdGroupName Impressions Clicks  Cost
Группа №2952489 10905034    939944  575118050000
Группа №2952490 10976444    944645  576994320000
Группа №2952491 10926208    947145  580294830000
Группа №2952492 10851243    945256  574691690000
Группа №2952493 10844346    946921  578424030000
Total rows: 5
```

Как мне его в массив преобразовать, чтобы значения соответствовали ключам?

```
'AdGroupName' => 'Группа №2952489' , Impressions    => '10905034',  ........
```

Comment: разделители табуляции или пробелы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чуть-чуть доработал ответ teran:

```
$str = preg_replace("/Total rows:(.*)/", "", $str);  
$str =  explode("\n", $str) ;
unset($str[0]);
unset($str[1]);

foreach($str as $line){
  if(!empty($line)){
    list($gn, $imp, $cl, $coast) = explode("\t", $line);
    $linearray = array(
        "AdGroupName" => $gn,
        "Imp" => $imp,
        "clicks" => $cl,
        "coast" => $coast,
    );
  print_R($linearray);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

предположим, что `tsv` это *tab separated values* и разделитель табуляция

Исходные

```
$txt =<<<TEXT
"a259784,259785 (2017-03-19 - 2018-03-19)"
AdGroupName Impressions Clicks  Cost
Группа №2952489 10905034    939944  575118050000
Группа №2952490 10976444    944645  576994320000
Группа №2952491 10926208    947145  580294830000
Группа №2952492 10851243    945256  574691690000
Группа №2952493 10844346    946921  578424030000
Total rows: 5
TEXT;
```

разделим на строки

```
$data = explode("\n", $txt);
```

Уберем первую и последнюю

```
array_shift($data);
array_pop($data);
```

первая строка = ключи, делим по табу

```
$keys = explode("\t", array_shift($data));
```

остальное тоже по табу и сливаем с ключами

```
$result = array_map(function($v) use ($keys){.
                return array_combine($keys, explode("\t", $v));
            }, $data);

print_r($result);
```